# Fail to open a socket for multicast

Tags: erlang, sockets, multicast, zeroconf

I have problems to open an multicast socket in Erlang to receive messages:

```
88> gen_udp:open(5353,[{reuseaddr, true}, {ip,{224,0,0,251}},{multicast_ttl,4},{multicast_loop,false},binary]).
{error,eaddrnotavail}
```

I checkt diffrent IP addresses and ports and the option {active, false}, but nothing helps. What could be the reason?

Thanks, Matthias.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the option `{add_membership, {Addr, LAddr}}` where:

1. Addr is the multicast group in question (e.g. 224.0.0.251)
2. LAddr is a local interface (e.g. 0.0.0.0 for the default one)

> 1> gen_udp:open(5353,[{reuseaddr,
>   true}, {add_membership, {{224, 0,0,
>   251}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}},
>   {ip,{224,0,0,251}},{multicast_ttl,4},{multicast_loop,false},binary]).
>
> {ok,#Port<0.454>}

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer! 
No positive effect :-(
Is this a router or a local computer problem?
Regards, Matthias

Comment: But OK, if I try this... (see below) I get a new error with a new hint about the possible problem. Thanks!

99> gen_udp:open(5353,[{reuseaddr, true},{add_membership, {{224, 0,0, 251}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}},{multicast_ttl,4},{multicast_loop,false},binary]).
{error,eaddrinuse}

Comment: if this is on OSX or Windows running Bonjour you are not going to be able to send on 5353. I can open and listen on 5353 but I still have not beem able to send on that port from Erlang.

http://github.com/fuzzylollipop/inet_mdns/blob/master/src/inet_mdns.erl

Comment: @fuzzy: Zeroconf/Bonjour might tie up this port and not share it: I wouldn't expect anything different. Running different servers on the same port would be sort of confusing to say the least.

Comment: With your first tip, the symptoms are the same {error,eaddrnotavail}on my Windows XP. Also, another port or another multicast IP does not help.

Comment: @Matthias: have you quit Bonjour instances?

Comment: Yes all. I killed additionally the virus scanner and firewall ... but I still have the same problem, also with other multicast IP addresses like (224.1.2.3) and with other ports like 1234.